# Create a json parsable k8s configmaps containing lists of quoted elements with Helm

Tags: json, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I was trying to modify a helm chart ([this one](https://github.com/pelias/kubernetes)), and one template is there to generate a configMap.

The config map is then loaded and parsed as a json by the different modules.

The thing is that I need at some point to put a list of strings in the json. Passing just the value in the template resulted in a not quoted list. I tried then to use a range to do it element by element, but then I get a final comma. And the json parser used by the image I’m deploying (over which I have no control) won't accept a non strict json. I.e., the last element in the list cannot have a trailing comma.

Here is an example `values.yaml`:

```
val:
  - "a"
  - "b"
  - "c"
```

And some `template.tpl`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: some-configmap
data:
  cfg.json: |
    {
      "val": [{{ range .Values.val }}{{ . | quote }},{{ end }}]
    }
```

But this yields:

```
{
  "val": ["a","b","c",]
}
```

Which is rejected by the json parser with message like:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1008
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: /etc/config/..2020_08_03_15_32_26.221540866/pelias.json: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 1744
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1005:27)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at getConfig (/code/pelias/schema/node_modules/pelias-config/index.js:66:21)
    at Object.generate (/code/pelias/schema/node_modules/pelias-config/index.js:24:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/code/pelias/schema/scripts/create_index.js:2:41)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
```

If I pass only empty lists, the json parser is happy, but I need those arguments for the rest of the process.

Is there a way to either remove the last comma, or even to load a list of strings in a more elegant manner using helm templates?

(I know I can hardcode the value in my templates, but I would like this deployment to be reusable with other parameters)

Thanks in advance.

**[EDIT]**

I found a somewhat working strategy by doing:
`"val": [{{ join "," .Values.val }}]`

The only issue now is that I need to use double quotes in my `values.yaml`:

```
val:
  - '"a"'
  - '"b"'
  - '"c"'
```

This is ok, but I'd be interested in a cleaner solution if anyone has it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toJson` function to convert sections (in your case of your values file) into JSON:

Both of those work (the difference being what you prefer and whether there are other functions you want to apply before):

```
"val": {{ toJson .Values.val }}
```

```
"val": {{ .Values.val | toJson }}
```

There is also a `toYaml` function.

---

### Examples

All examples use a slightly modified `values.yaml`:

```yaml
config:
  val:
    - a
    - b
    - c
```

#### Example 1: Just the array

```
data:
  cfg.json: |-
    {
      "val": {{ toJson .Values.config.val }}
    }
```

results in

```
data:
  cfg.json: |-
    {
      "val": ["a","b","c"]
    }
```

#### Example 2: The whole section

```
data:
  cfg.json: {{ .Values.config | toJson | quote }}
```

results in

```
data:
  cfg.json: "{\"val\":[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]}"
```

#### Example 3: Pretty JSON

```
data:
  cfg.json: |-
    {{- .Values.config | toPrettyJson | nindent 4 }}
```

results in

```
data:
  cfg.json: |-
    {
      "val": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
      ]
    }
```

#### Example 4: YAML

```
data:
  cfg.json: |-
    {{- .Values.config | toYaml | nindent 4 }}
```

results in

```
data:
  cfg.json: |-
    val:
    - a
    - b
    - c
```